# Change Button text color

Tags: c#, winforms

When we pass the mouse over a button we can change the button back color using `MouseOverBackColor` and `MouseDownBackColor` using `FlatApearance` property box.

How can I change a button text color in the same mode when the mouse pass over it?

Comment: I think you can't do it by FlatAppearance. But you can set ForeColor in MouseDown and MouseEnter, MouseLeave event.

Answer (score 5):

This should work for all sorts of `Buttons`, with or without `FlatAppearance`:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using **RGB** values, this can look like this:

```
//Hover Text Color changing
    private void btnHome_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnHome.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(1, 102, 207);
    }

    private void btnHome_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnHome.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
    }
```

don´t forget to do everytime a new method call for each button!

Just follow this figure to come to a nice solution:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change button text color when mouse is over the button:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
}
```